# R ggplot: specify aes by index

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot() +
layer(
 data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = carat, y = price),
 geom = "point", stat = "identity"
)
```

In the above example, I am wondering if I can specify the parameters for the "aes" function  by indexes.

I know that carat and price correspond to the 1st and 8th elements in the names array of diamond. Can you explain why the following does not work?

```
ggplot() +
layer(
 data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = names(diamonds)[1], y = names(diamonds)[8]),
 geom = "point", stat = "identity"
)
```

Thanks, Derek

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second version does not work because `names(diamonds)[1]` is `"carat"` and not `carat`. Use `aes_string` instead of `aes` for this to work.

```
ggplot( data = diamonds, mapping = aes_string(x = names(diamonds)[1], y = names(diamonds)[8]), stat = "identity")+ geom_point()
```

**EDIT:**
To deal with names that have illegal characters, you have to do enclose them in backticks (that's the case any time you want to use them):

```
dd <- data.frame(1:10, rnorm(1:10))
names(dd) <- c("(PDH-TSV 4.0)(ET)(240)", "Y")
nms <- paste("`", names(dd), "`", sep="")
ggplot(dd, mapping=aes_string(x=nms[1], y=nms[2])) + geom_point()
```

Comment: while aes_string works for one-word-names in data frame, it seems to have dealing with names that has space and punctuation.

For example, it shows the follow error when the name is "(PDH-TSV 4.0) (Eastern Daylight Time)(240)"

Error in parse(text = x) : unexpected numeric constant in "(PDH-TSV 4.0"